# Acceder a un elemento de un diccionario aleatoriamente o pasándole un argumento a la función

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Llevo días liados intentando hacer un juego en python, pero se nota que todavía soy un novato, porque llevo atascado en el principio desde el comienzo.

A ver si me podéis ayudar a resolver lo que quiero hacer muchas gracias.

Lo que tengo en mente es crear una clase más o menos así:

```
from random import choices
""" Importa choices para generar opciones aleatorios con una probabilidad específica. """

class Dados_jugador:
    caras = {
        "Guerrero":"Verde",
        "Templario":"Blanco",
        "Mago":"Azul"
    }

    def __init__(self, eleccion=None):
        if eleccion is None:
            pass
        else:
            pass

enemigo = Dados_jugador("argumento(?)")
```

Me gustaría que la clase devuelta aleatoriamente un par clave:valor del diccionario si no se le pasa ningún argumento. Y si se le pasa, que devuelva el par clave:valor específico.

Ese par clave:valor debería ser guardado en dos variables de estancia.

He probado todo lo que se me ocurre, pero no he conseguido nada.

Por otro lado, cuando se usa el método para obtener un par clave:valor aleatorio, me gustaría que se le diera un peso a cada posibilidad, por eso el import con choices.

Muchas gracias y perdonen las molestias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la forma en que funciona `random.choices` internamente se requiere que el iterable con las opciones sea indizable, un diccionario no lo es. Para usar un diccionario con `random.choices` necesitas pasar una lista/tupla con las claves o los items:

```
from random import choices

caras = {
    "Guerrero":"Verde",
    "Templario":"Blanco",
    "Mago":"Azul"
} 

cara = choices(list(caras), k=1)[0]
color = caras[cara]
print(cara, color)

cara, color = choices(list(caras.items()), k=1)[0]
print(cara, color)
```

Ahora bien, si queremos usar pesos, tenemos que tener en cuenta la versión de Python en la que el código se va a ejecutar. A **partir de Python 3.7 tenemos asegurado que los diccionarios mantienen el orden de inserción de sus items, pero esto no es así en versiones anteriores** (en Python 3.6 realmente también, solo que se considera un efecto colateral de la implementación).

Esto quiere decir que en Python < 3.7 el orden de los items cuando iteramos sobre un diccionario o usamos las vistas `dict.keys`, `dict.items`, `dict.values` no es predecible, por lo que los pesos se aplicaran a vete a saber que items del diccionario.

Si estamos totalmente seguros de que nuestro código se va a ejecutar en Python > 3.7 no hay problema en hacer:

```
cara, color = choices(list(caras.items()), weights=[1,2,1], k=1)[0]
```

Si no estamos seguros de esto no se debe hacer esto nunca. Tenemos varias soluciones, por ejemplo:

- Usar `collections.OrderedDict` en vez de un diccionario estándar:

  ```
  from collections import OrderedDict
  from random import choices

  caras = OrderedDict(
      (("Guerrero", "Verde"),
      ("Templario", "Blanco"),
      ("Mago", "Azul"))
  )

  cara, color = choices(list(caras.items()), weights=[1,2,1], k=1)[0]
  print(cara, color)
  ```
- Si queremos usar un diccionario de todas formas, debemos asegurarnos siempre de asociar correctamente cada clave con su peso. Podemos hacerlo de muchas formas, desde usando una tupla o lista accesoria con las claves del diccionario y usarla como opciones para choices a asociar cada peso a su clave dentro del propio diccionario:

  ```
  from random import choices

  caras = {
      "Guerrero":  {"color": "Verde",  "peso": 1},
      "Templario": {"color": "Blanco", "peso": 2},
      "Mago":      {"color": "Azul",   "peso": 1},
  }

  cara = choices(list(caras), weights=[v["peso"] for v in caras.values()], k=1)[0]
  color = caras[cara]["color"]
  print(cara, color)
  ```

  > En Python <= 3.7 no se asegura el orden de inserción, pero si se asegura que las vistas de un diccionario (o irteraciones sobre el mismo) mantienen el mismo orden (el que sea, eso no lo podemos asegurar) mientras el diccionario no sea modificado.

Answer (score 0):

al final, la solución más sencilla ha sido la idónea.

Publico la respuesta por si a alguien le puede ser de ayuda (intentaba complicarme demasiado cuando la solución era relativamente fácil).

```py
from random import choices
""" Importa choices para generar opciones aleatorios con una probabilidad específica. """

class Dados_jugador:
    caras = {
        "Guerrero":"Verde",
        "Templario":"Blanco",
        "Mago":"Azul"
    }

    def __init__(self, eleccion=None):
        if eleccion is None:
            """ print(choices(list(Dados_jugador.caras.items()))) """
            posibilidades = [i for i in Dados_jugador.caras.keys()]
            eleccion = choices(posibilidades, weights=[1,2,1])
            self.personaje, self.color = eleccion[0], Dados_jugador.caras[eleccion[0]]
        else:
            self.personaje, self.color = eleccion, Dados_jugador.caras[eleccion]
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si usas Python < 3.7 ese código es técnicamente  incorrecto, no tienes asegurado que los pesos se apliquen a la cara correspondiente porque los diccionarios no mantienen el orden de inserción.

Comment: Buenas,

Gracias por el consejo. Actualmente uso la versión 3.7.4. No debería tener problema con esa versión, ¿no?

Comment: Si sabes con toda seguridad que no va a ejecutarse en versiones anteriores a 3.7.x no hay problema alguno, en caso contrario la aplicación de los pesos es impredecible. He creado una respuesta aclarando esto entre otras cosas. Un saludo.